# What is the purpose of "draw" parameter?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Both request and response in jQuery DataTables have `draw` parameter. What is the purpose of this parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters):

> This is used by DataTables to ensure that the Ajax returns from server-side processing requests are drawn in sequence by DataTables (Ajax requests are asynchronous and thus can return out of sequence).

In [response](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) value of `draw` parameter must match value of `draw` parameter from the [request](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters).

However some think it's not needed and author of jQuery DataTables is considering to remove it in 1.11 release, see [discussion at github](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/600).